# Microsoft Intune - cannot add device

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows, intune

I have developed a windows store app and we would like to have a way to distribute it (and manage updates) to a certain number of company machines (some use Windows 10, other Windows 8.1).

First I tried using a Windows Intune trial but encountered a problem. I cannot register a device that runs on 8.1. I arrive at the step where I must connect the machine to a workplace (via PC Settings - Network - Workplace - Join) but I get the error  "Confirm you are using the correct sign-in info, and that your workplace uses this feature. Also, the connection to your workplace might not be working right now. Please wait and try again." I am trying to connect by using the trial account I created when I started the Intune trial (ex: xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com). Also, I do not see an option in Intune that lets me update existing apps on a device. Have I missed a step?

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Microsoft support team several times and ran through the deployment. We could not make it work. In the end, they told me to use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue due to my local network issue. Make sure your network is not restricting anything. (I also used trial version of Intune)

Intune lets you update the newer version of the app. (Must be the same app, you can't replace with a different app through). You can push or 'Available install' the app updates.

To do this goto App section of the intune, select the app and edit it. Then upload the latest version of your app. Intune will detect that as an update and will push or make available via 'Company Portal' app.

-Hope this helps